# My NFC Reader cannot successfully read the right data

Tags: android, nfc

I have developed a simple NFC app which will launch after sensing the NFC tag. There are two questions I would like to ask, why after my program launch, I need to let the device to sense the tag again whether than it will just read the tag after it launch? And, I have set the data type to read as text/plain, but why when I output the data in a textview field, a meaningless query appear?

```
public class Reader extends Activity {

TextView mText;
NfcAdapter mAdapter;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
IntentFilter mFilters[];
String mTechLists[][];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);

    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try{
        ndef.addDataType("text/plain");
    }catch(MalformedMimeTypeException e){
        throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
    }

    IntentFilter nt = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    mFilters = new IntentFilter[]{
            ndef, nt
    };

    mTechLists = new String[][]{
            new String[]{
                    Ndef.class.getName()
            }
    };
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mText.setText(getNdefMessages(intent));
}

public String getNdefMessages(Intent intent){
    NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)||
            NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)){
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if(rawMsgs != null){
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for(int i=0; i<rawMsgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }else{
            byte[] empty = new byte[]{};
            NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, empty, empty);
            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{record});
            msgs = new NdefMessage[]{msg};
        }

    }
    if(msgs==null)
        return "No Tag discovered!";
    else
        return msgs.toString();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdapter != null)
        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mFilters, mTechLists);

}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (mAdapter != null)
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Log.i("Foreground dispatch", "Discovered tag with intent:" + intent);
    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mText.setText(getNdefMessages(intent));
}

}
```

Above is my main program, and below is the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="android.reader"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="10" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity 
        android:name=".Reader"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reader">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" /> 
            <!--<data 
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="developer.android.com"/>-->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Message shows in the app:

[image]

At last is the data I input into the tag:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NdefMessage` is an object that contains one or more `NdefRecord`s. Call `yourNdefMessage.getRecords()` to access them.

An `NdefRecord` can have various types with accompanying content, including plain text. There are 2 types of plain text `NdefRecord`s: Well-Known Type Text and MIME-type "text/plain" (both use the same intent filter; see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#ndef for details).

You seem to use the MIME-type text/plain. So you can easily convert it to a String: `new String(yourNdefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload())`.

To make sure your app can immediately access the tag when started you should put the Android Application Record as the last record in the NDEF message. Otherwise the generated intent will contain the action MAIN instead of NDEF_DISCOVERED and there will be no NDEF message and TAG EXTRAs in the intent.

Comment: By google, I finally find this method to access the playload, but when I have two records or even more, what is the ways to get those records, I tried to get the second one by msgs[1].getRecords()[0].getPayload(), but the system replys me index out of bound

Comment: I have tried to output some values both length of rawMsgs and Msgs[0].getReord() are of length 1, may I ask where is the second record?

Comment: There is one NDEF message with multiple records, so `msgs[0].getRecords()[1]` is the 2nd record of the first (and only) NDEF message.

Comment: I would like to ask if it is possible to create mutiple Ndef message in a tag, because when I use the app to write on the tag, everytime it will replace the last one, therefore it will only keep one Ndef message at most?

Comment: And after I change it to read two datas one, it can seldom get the values at once it launches, but need to put the tag near to the devices maybe a few times before it can read it, is it the problem of the hardware or my program?

Comment: Android does not support multiple NDEF messages on a tag. (In theory it is possible, but I have never seen it being used anywhere.) Your phone makes a sound when it detects a tag. If you do not hear that sound (and your phone's sound is not turned off), there may be a problem with the tag's antenna.

Comment: I see, so the length of msgs is always one. Actually, in theory my program should be able to read the data and show it after it launches, however, usually it needs to sense a few time before values being shown. But I have not changed the logic of the program, just modified it from return string to string array, so can get mutiple records. What are the possible reasons leading to this change?

Comment: That is not clear to me. What is different in your code is that the logic that is usually in `onCreate()` you have in `onStart()`. Not sure whether that matters, though. The last screenshot shows an AAR. Is that the first or the last record?

Comment: AAR should be the last record, because I have output the record. I have followed your advice to make those codes back to onCreate, things get better, but still cannot get the value shown in the TextView when first launch from teh home screen, instead it shows the values when the program launch and senses the tag again.